# Magento - Hide "Subtotal" and show only grand total in /checkout/onepage/

Tags: magento

I want to hide the line "Subtotal" in Magento /checkout/onepage/ and show only the "grand total" line.

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the file located in: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml to:

```
<?php if ($this->getTotals()): ?>
<tfoot>
<?php $_colspan = $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 5 : 3; ?>
<?php //echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan); ?>
<?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer', $_colspan); ?>
<?php if ($this->needDisplayBaseGrandtotal()):?>
  <tr>
    <td class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $_colspan; ?>">
        <small><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Your credit card will be charged for')      ?></small>
    </td>
    <td class="a-right">
        <small><?php echo $this->displayBaseGrandtotal() ?></small>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif?>
```

Your path may be different if you use a custome theme or running on versions older than 1.5.X.X (1.4 uses default/default instead of base/default as far as i remember).

Also note that i only commented out the line echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan); and you may have to do it different, acording to your display tax rules. but anyway, that is the file showing the totals..

Comment: Thanks a lot, and how to hide it in the order validation Email ?

Comment: in my sales.xml (located in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout) - see the section <sales_email_order_items> the template for the totals in the mail is: app/design/frontend/base/default/sales/order/totals.phtml - so thats the file to edit.

Comment: How to do it exactly ? 

Thanks for help :)